# How can I take click Value with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, if-statement, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I am new to use Seleniumn ide , I want to use if else condition for my web page view.

About page view has 2 different webpage like there is a button when i push it it shows me detail view. when i push in the same button it show me list view so that i want to check when i start to use selenium ide first page Detail view. if selenium start and see list view i want to turn it to detail view.

i want to use for this

command          |        target          |     value

if                (condition===false)
  click      button path (for detail view)

else 
     do nothing

end

Comment: could you provide any code of the html page and what have you tried with selenium

Comment: I haven't tried yet anything because it doesnt work. The button is the same just one click it the page is changing and the button is xpath is changing so This is my Detail button  xpath 'css=.tlButtons > #changeView '   and this is my List page button  xpath 'css=.prodAcBtnSet > #changeView'   . I want to do this for example  i should find value of the Detail button value if the value is belongs to Detail page then i dont want to nothing but if the button value belongs to List page then i want to click this css=.tlButtons > #changeView then i can control the Detail page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find xpath, that can be found only in list view or detail view. For example, `list_view_xpath` - xpath that can be found on list view page and cannot be found on detail view page.

```
wait for element visible | xpath=page_is_loaded | 30000
store xpath count | xpath=list_view_xpath | n
if| ${n} == 1 | 
 click | xpath=detail_view_button |
end
```

where `page_is_loaded` - xpath indicates that page has been shown and `detail_view_button` - xpath of button that changes page view.